# equivalent of rowlock xlock holdlock (sql server) for postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

in sql server

```
begin tran
    select * from foos with (rowlock, xlock, holdlock) where id =7 
...
commit tran
```

will **lock the row for reading and writing and it will hold the lock until the end of the transaction**,

is there an equivalent of this in postgresql ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
BEGIN tran;
    SELECT * FROM foos FOR UPDATE;
...
COMMIT tran;
```

Reference: [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pg_advisory_lock()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html)